# How can i return hash map from server to client

Tags: gwt

I have the following method on sever.

```
public HashMap<String,Set> select()
{
      HashMap <String,Set> mp = new HashMap();
     //some code
  return mp;
 }
```

whenver I am trying to return

```
 <String , Set>
```

it is going onFailur
 but I did this

```
  <String , String >
```

then its success why this happning

i am using gwt RPC and my client code is

```
  greetingService.select(usertextbox.getText(),new AsyncCallback<HashMap<String,Set>>()
                                    {
                                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) { 

                                            Window.alert("not done");
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(HashMap hm) {
 Window.alert("done");
 }
```

Service code is

```
  HashMap<String, Set> select(String user);
```

service implmentation is

```
public HashMap<String,Set> select(String user)
{
    try {

          Session studentDbSession = new Session("localhost",5984);

          Database db = studentDbSession.getDatabase("hello");

          Document d = db.getDocument("xyz");

          JSONArray key = d.names().discard(0).discard(0);
          for(int i=0;i<key.size();i++)
          {

              if(d.containsKey(key.get(i)))
               {
                    k=key.getString(i);

                   Set aaa=d.getJSONObject(key.getString(i)).entrySet();
                   System.out.println("----------------");
                      mp.put(k,aaa);
return mp;
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any exception? How are doing it? Share some piece of code.

Comment: there is no exception

Comment: it just going on fail

Comment: Are you using GWT RPC? Share code for serviceImpl, serviceAsync and client side code

Comment: please read edited question

Comment: why `Set` is not generic? Why using raw type here?

Comment: actualy  I have a key like name which contain some value with one more key and value like ( course=graduation,subject=computer science) how can i achiva this

Comment: your code is not testable and not complete. Try with my sample code first or validate your classes.

Comment: ok i am trying but is there any collection to store like(key:[key:value])

Comment: A Map that contains another Map. Right?

Comment: Yes you can do it easily and it works. Should I update it in my post?

Comment: ok but i have duplicate key like(mark:class:math),(Braj:class:computer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55123/discussion-between-mark-and-braj).

Answer (score 2):

Always try to avoid **Raw** type. Let me share you a sample code. Try it at you end with this sample first or validate all the classes of your code.

#### Sample code:

RemoteService interface

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
    public HashMap<String, Set<String>> select(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

GreetingServiceAsync interface

```
public interface GreetingServiceAsync {
    void select(String input, AsyncCallback<HashMap<String, Set<String>>> callback);
}
```

GreetingServiceImpl class

```
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GreetingService {

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Set<String>> select(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        HashMap<String, Set<String>> output = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        set.add("Hello " + input);

        output.put("greeting", set);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Entry Point class

```
public void greetService() {
    GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);

    greetingService.select("Mark", new AsyncCallback<HashMap<String, Set<String>>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(HashMap<String, Set<String>> result) {
            Window.alert(result.get("greeting").iterator().next());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Window.alert("fail");
        }
    });
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gwtService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.x.y.z.server.GWTServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gwtService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/moduleName/gwtService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: What failure are you talking about? Can you explain a bit more about the failure term?

Comment: i am getting a alert of fail

Comment: It means there is an exception. Print `caught.printStackTrace()` there is with with you service.

Comment: no there is not any exception i am getting a error code on devlopment mode of jety 500 - POST /singledoc/greet (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes

Comment: 500 means The call failed on the server. see server log for details. There is some exception in your serviceImpl class.

Comment: sorry but there is no exception

Comment: Set aaa=d.getJSONObject(key.getString(i)).entrySet();
                   System.out.println("----------------");
                      mp.put(k,aaa);
return mp; ....................this code is responsible for fail

Comment: Enclose it inside the `try-catch` block and print stack trace in catch block to investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What your GWT RPC call `HashMap<String, Set> select(String user);` does is following:

1. client-side: serialize `String user` in order to send it to server
2. server-side: deserialize RPC call, find implementation of `select(String user)` and execute it
3. server-side: serialize return value `HashMap<String, Set>` in order to return it to client
4. client-side: deserialize return value and call AsyncCallback

The problem lies in step 3), the serializing of `HashMap<String, Set>`. The HashMap itself is not the issue; it is the `Set` which causes the error. When serializing a raw class, GWT usually assumes that the generic type is `<Object>`. And since `Object` is not serializable in GWT, an exception is thrown.

**Fix**: As Braj already mentioned -- give your Set a serializible generic type, e. g. `Set<String>`, or define your own interface in a package which is *accessable from both client- and server-side*

```
public interface UserProperty extends IsSerializable{
}
```

and change the RPC method like this:

```
HashMap<String, Set<UserProperty> select(String user);
```

Have a look at Braj's answer for where to find all the places you need to change after changing your RPC method!